# Python telnet connection abruptly ends

Tags: python, routes, telnet

I'm currently working on a programme to automate some function for router configuration and I've managed to create a loopback interface between GNS3 and my computer so that I can connect python via telnet.

At first, the code ran smoothly and I had no problem, but when I switched to another router, it works only for a few commands and then it suddenly stops and I can't figure why.

This is the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Licenta - program\test1\main.py", line 147, in <module>
    tn.write(b"ip add ")
  File "C:\Users\carme\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\telnetlib.py", line 292, in write
    self.sock.sendall(buffer)
ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
```

Any suggestions are welcomed!

Thank you!

Comment: What happens on the server side? Have you checked what happens on the router?

Comment: The server side is offline.